# Woocommerce - Move add to cart button variable product

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I am working on a custom theme. I need to move the add to cart button from the woocommerce_single_variation (variable.php) section into the woocommerce_after_single_product_summary (content-single-product.php) section.

I have been able to do this by adding the following to my functions.php file.

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 30 );
```

However when I do this the button shows up but is not functional. Clicking on it just does nothing. Does anyone know is it possible to move the add to cart button in such a way? Please note this is for variable products not single so I'm thinking the behavior is different.

I appreciate any help that can be given. Thanks!

Comment: It could not work because, in this way the button is getting out the form tags! …  Check the generated html, you will see what i mean.

Comment: Thanks! I just had a light bulb moment while reading your answer. That makes perfect sense. Thanks again. We'll have to try something else to get the look we want.

Answer (score 1):

As @LoicTheAztec mentioned, your `add to cart` button moved out from the product form, so it won't do anything unless you write some `JS` to simulate that `submit` action.

```
function inject_add_cart_form_script() { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){
    $(document).on( 'click', 'single_add_to_cart_button', function(){
        $('form.cart').submit();
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
<?php 
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'inject_add_cart_form_script');
```