# Move product variations without Add to Cart button to sidebar

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

I'm trying to move the product variations from woocommerce_single_variation (single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php) to Genesis Sidebar, but i want to keep the Add to Cart button in woocommerce_single_product_summary. I tried at first to move only variations like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
add_action('genesis_sidebar','woocommerce_single_variation', 5 );
```

but didn't work. So i moved the entire variations block to sidebar:

```
/* Remove variations and add to cart button */
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action('genesis_sidebar','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 5 );
```

and added back the add to cart button to the product summary:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 5 );
```

My problem now is that the add to cart button is not working anymore, so I need to simulate the add to cart action. I tried this answer but is not working: [Woocommerce - Move add to cart button variable product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517525/woocommerce-move-add-to-cart-button-variable-product)

Any other solution is welcome, Thank you!

Comment: What is the link build on your add to cart button? Is it like http://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=123 ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply i just saw your comment. Yes is like that.

Comment: In that case, you can just put the link of such add to cart action and add it to cart.