# Moving WooCommerce add to cart button on single product page without variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[Moving add to cart button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBjwG.png)

As you can see, I'm tying to move add to cart button without moving variations, I achieved that by using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517525/woocommerce-move-add-to-cart-button-variable-product).

However, the button after replacement becomes unusable, because it doesn't work, as it is out of the form.

So my question is how to move that button without the variations and without loosing it's functionality?

Comment: in the question you provided also have answer. do you tried the answer code from that question?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, the code doesn't work, the add button remains inactive!